# How to call jquery function from file on pageload?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to my jquery function `initDatePicker()` into a js file. The function should require a parameter. I want the function being called on pageload.

Tried the following, but I'm probably missing some pieces here?

datepicker.js:

```
$(function initDatePicker(startDate) {
        ...
});
```

html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@{/js/datepicker.js}">
    $(function() {
        initDatePicker('-1d');
    });
</script>
```

- Is my function definition correct in `datepicker.js`?
- How do I correctly call the function on pageload with providing a parameter?

Comment: You shouldn't have `$(` `)` around your function definition in datepicker.js. (That tells jQuery to call the function on page load, but that doesn't give you the opportunity to pass in a start date.) The way you call it in the HTML looks fine, though make sure you have separate script elements for loading the external script and for the embedded script, as one element can't do both.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @deltab I could solve it as follows:

```
function initDatePicker(startDate) {
        ...
};
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@{/js/datepicker.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><
    $(function() {
        initDatePicker('-1d');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
     initDatePicker('-1d');
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Please add some context why you think this is a useful answer. See also [answer].